# Mongo no longer connects

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB was running fine, but now it won't connect. When I run mongo, I get this message:

```
warm@ULTP-500:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-01-13T15:53:18.609+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 
127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: 
Connection refused

2018-01-13T15:53:18.609+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't 
connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I have tried restarting the mongod service, but that doesn't help. Can you please guide me on how to debug this issue?

Comment: can you check the logs?

Comment: actually i am new here how can i check the log in ubuntu?

Comment: check you configuration usually in `/etc/mongod.conf` it will have the directory for data and logs

Comment: yes there is mongod.conf file is there

Comment: check the conf file, it will have log path something like this `path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: yes but in that directory no log file is there /var/log/mongodb/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163099/discussion-between-zaif-warm-and-saravana).